# Sybase Multiple Substrings Search

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I need to get data back from a text field.  The input is not all going to be pretty...some of the users don't spell well or consistently.  I need to look for a variety of misspellings as well as alternative terms.

I am working with Sybase ASE and am wondering if the AND statement is getting unwieldy and may not be optimal?  Here is one attempt:

```
AND (entry_txt like 'fight' OR
    entry_txt like 'confron%' OR
    entry_txt like 'aggres%' OR
    entry_txt like 'grab' OR
    entry_txt like 'push' OR
    entry_txt like 'strike' OR
    entry_txt like 'hit' OR
    entry_txt like 'assa%')
```

It will get longer as I add some new requirements for additional terms as well as some proprietary names and 8-9 more variations therein!  Is there a more efficient way to do this or is that it?

I have also read that LIKE should be used for partial string comparison and IN for values from a set.  How about values from a set of partial strings?  Could I /should I use IN here and does that help performance?

I am searching thousands of docs so there is a lot of data to have to go through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for the ones that you don't have `%` you can use `IN`, for the others you still need to use `OR`.

It would look something like this:

```
AND (entry_txt in ('fight', 'grab', 'push', 'strike', 'hit')
     OR entry_txt like 'confron%'
     OR entry_txt like 'aggres%'
     OR entry_txt like 'assa%')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually put "like" expressions in an expression - another column in a table, or a variable.

So you could create a table with one varchar column called "like_expr" or something like that.

Then put all the above expressions into it, including the ones without % in, because they'll just degenerate to an equality operation.

In terms of efficiency, if entry_txt is indexed then the index can be used.  I would think Sybase would find it easier to join to the like_expr table than to do lots and lots of ORs, but both should use the index - that should be a separate issue.)

create table abe (a varchar(20))

insert abe values ('hello')

create table abe2 (l varchar(20))

insert abe2 values ('h%')

select * from abe a where exists (select 1 from abe2 where a.a like l)

### a

hello

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would suggest you review your answer's formatting. There seems to be value here, but it isn't easy to read. Code should be identified as code, for example. Also, it seems like the formatting tripped you up at the end there too. You can preview your answers before submitting them to ensure proper layout.

Comment: So you are comparing the information in the abe2 table against the terms that exist in the current table.  It could even be a temp table #abe2 since I won't need this table again until next year at which time I can recreate it again.  I save all the queries I write in a file so I can refer to them later and recycle them.  It would look like --      Select entry_text from abe a where exists(select entry_exp from #abe2 b where a.entry_txt like b.entry_exp)